# Task bar icons on Windows with Java bundled app

Tags: java, icons, taskbar

I used launch4j to wrap my jar file into an .exe. The app has my icon, but the icon in the task bar is the plain Java icon, which I would prefer not to have. On Mac, I've bundled the same jar into a .app using ant and appbundler, and the icon in the dock is fine.

If it's running on Windows, I've tried

```
icon = new Image("/Icon-16x16.ico");
mainWindow.getIcons().add(icon);
```

where mainWindow is a Stage, but it doesn't work. That is, it still shows the Java icon in the TaskBar.

OK, I solved the problem. The above works perfectly with .png files. It does not work with .ico files.

Answer (score 1):

The asker posted this as the fix:

> The above works perfectly with .png files. It does not work with .ico files.